# How to redirect blogger post to another url, It worked in desktop view but not working in mobile view. Please tell correct code?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, redirect

//Javascript Code for redirecting a blogger post url to another url.
// Already chose Desktop theme for mobile devices.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  if(window.location.href == 'https://example.blogspot.com/2021/03/blog-post.html') {
  document.location = "https://amazon.com/";
    if (screen.width < 699) {
    document.location = "https://amazon.com/";
    }
  }
</script>
```

//It would be very helpful if you provide code for redirecting post url to another url.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `screen.width` try `window.innerWidth` and instead of `document.location` try `window.location`